# Bigquery request on multiple tables

Tags: google-bigquery, request

I would like to request on several tables with the following format name :

```
project.dataset.fr_table_20221001
project.dataset.fr_table_20221002
...
project.dataset.fr_table_20221030

project.dataset.en_table_20221001
project.dataset.en_table_20221002
...
project.dataset.en_table_20221030
```

etc with multiple langages and other dates.

Do you know what is the good syntax? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi @badinmaths, can you clarify your requirement by providing sample input and sample output?

Answer (score 0):

By request did you mean retrieving table names on a specific dataset?

Can you try this query:

```
  SELECT
    CONCAT(table_catalog,'.',table_schema,'.',table_name) as Result
  FROM
    cars.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

you can change `cars` to your dataset to view the list of tables from yours. Please see sample output:
[image]